# Apache SSL error after reboot: Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR)

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

Google Chrome shows: "Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR)" everytime I reboot my server.
However, if I restart apache(# service apache2 restart), everything works great.

Nothing appears on Apache error log(/var/log/apache2/error.log), and I'm using debian 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved!!

The setting in ports.conf was:

```
 <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
     Listen 443
    NameVirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443 # ipv4
    NameVirtualHost 1:2::3:4:5:6:443 # ipv6
 </IfModule>
```

sites-available/default-ssl was:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:443>
...
...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 1:2::3:4:5:6:443>
...# same setting as ipv4
...
</VirtualHost>
```

When I fix this to the following, https works after rebooting!

ports.conf:

```
 <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
     Listen 443
    NameVirtualHost *:443
 </IfModule>
```

sites-available/default-ssl:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
...
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks to these two pages although it's not the same problem:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=806884
http://www.noah.org/wiki/Apache2_Invalid_method_in_request_%5Cx16%5Cx03%5Cx01

Comment: That's a strange config to have - it's definitely non-default, since you have your own IP address in there!  Do you have any software installed that managed or modifies your Apache configuration?

Comment: It was set by myself from some tutorials on Google...