# SSL Error 107 - Apache2 SSL config

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-12.04, mod-ssl, google-chrome

I'm trying to configure a new web server to host a website/php application. All web traffic to this server is supposed to be through https. I've read numerous tutorials as well as the Apache docs and wiki about how to set this up. I also [recently posted on SF](https://serverfault.com/questions/499429/setting-up-ssl-recompiling-apache-with-mod-ssl) about an issue I was having testing a mock setup of this on a local computer (I mention this only to point out that I am sure I am not repeating the same mistake).

The server is running Ubuntu 12.04 64bit with Apache2 v2.2.22 and currently it is only required to host this one website/php app.

My problem is that after setting this up (getting a cert from a CA, enabling mod_ssl, editing virtual host configs, setting up the https redirect for http traffic, restarting apache etc etc) when I go to my server in my browser (Chromium running on Linux Mint 14) I just get an SSL Error 107:

```
SSL connection error
Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.
```

Here is all the info I can gather on my config and the error:

My ports.conf:

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
# This is also true if you have upgraded from before 2.2.9-3 (i.e. from
# Debian etch). See /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/NEWS.Debian.gz and
# README.Debian.gz

NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

I added the NameVirtualHost *:443  line because of [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/399350/apache-ssl-error-after-reboot-error-107-neterr-ssl-protocol-error), but I don't know if it does anything (as the comment suggests, it is matched in the vh config, see below)

Here is the virtual host config file for the site (stored in sites-available and enabled with a2ensite command)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@my-app.com
    ServerName login.my-app.com     
    Redirect permanent / https://login.my-app.com
</VirtualHost>


<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@my-app.com


    #DocumentRoot /var/www/login.my-app.com
    ServerName login.my-app.com

    #Do these really do anything?
    #Alias /login.my-app.com /var/www/login.my-app.com
    #UserDir disabled root  

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from all
        #SSLRequireSSL
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        #SSLRequireSSL
    </Directory>


    <Directory /var/www/login.my-app.com>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        SSLRequireSSL
        </Directory>


    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/login.my-app.com.error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

    #   SSL Engine Switch:
    #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
    SSLEngine on


    #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
    #   the ssl-cert package. See
    #   /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/README.Debian.gz for more info.
    #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
    #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
    #SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    #SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/my-app.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/my-app.com.key

    #   Server Certificate Chain:
    #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
    #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
    #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
    #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
    #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
    #   certificate for convinience.
    #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server-ca.crt
    # not sure if this one is used if Certificate Authority (CA) below is used?
    #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/intermediate.crt

    #   Certificate Authority (CA):
    #   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
    #   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
    #   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
    #   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
    #         to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
    #         Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
    #SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs/
    #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/intermediate.crt

    #   Certificate Revocation Lists (CRL):
    #   Set the CA revocation path where to find CA CRLs for client
    #   authentication or alternatively one huge file containing all
    #   of them (file must be PEM encoded)
    #   Note: Inside SSLCARevocationPath you need hash symlinks
    #         to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
    #         Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
    #SSLCARevocationPath /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/
    #SSLCARevocationFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl

    #   Client Authentication (Type):
    #   Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
    #   none, optional, require and optional_no_ca.  Depth is a
    #   number which specifies how deeply to verify the certificate
    #   issuer chain before deciding the certificate is not valid.
    #SSLVerifyClient require
    #SSLVerifyDepth  10

    #   Access Control:
    #   With SSLRequire you can do per-directory access control based
    #   on arbitrary complex boolean expressions containing server
    #   variable checks and other lookup directives.  The syntax is a
    #   mixture between C and Perl.  See the mod_ssl documentation
    #   for more details.
    #<Location />
    #SSLRequire (    %{SSL_CIPHER} !~ m/^(EXP|NULL)/ \
    #            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O} eq "Snake Oil, Ltd." \
    #            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} in {"Staff", "CA", "Dev"} \
    #            and %{TIME_WDAY} >= 1 and %{TIME_WDAY} <= 5 \
    #            and %{TIME_HOUR} >= 8 and %{TIME_HOUR} <= 20       ) \
    #           or %{REMOTE_ADDR} =~ m/^192\.76\.162\.[0-9]+$/
    #</Location>

    #   SSL Engine Options:
    #   Set various options for the SSL engine.
    #   o FakeBasicAuth:
    #     Translate the client X.509 into a Basic Authorisation.  This means that
    #     the standard Auth/DBMAuth methods can be used for access control.  The
    #     user name is the `one line' version of the client's X.509 certificate.
    #     Note that no password is obtained from the user. Every entry in the user
    #     file needs this password: `xxj31ZMTZzkVA'.
    #   o ExportCertData:
    #     This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
    #     SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
    #     server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
    #     authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
    #     into CGI scripts.
    #   o StdEnvVars:
    #     This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
    #     Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
    #     because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
    #     useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
    #     exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
    #   o StrictRequire:
    #     This denies access when "SSLRequireSSL" or "SSLRequire" applied even
    #     under a "Satisfy any" situation, i.e. when it applies access is denied
    #     and no other module can change it.
    #   o OptRenegotiate:
    #     This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
    #     directives are used in per-directory context.
    #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    #   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
    #   The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
    #   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
    #   the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
    #   approach you can use one of the following variables:
    #   o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
    #     This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
    #     SSL close notify alert is send or allowed to received.  This violates
    #     the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
    #     this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
    #     mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
    #   o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
    #     This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
    #     SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
    #     alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
    #     practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
    #     this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
    #     works correctly.
    #   Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
    #   keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
    #   keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
    #   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
    #   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
    #   "force-response-1.0" for this.
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

As for error logs, login.my-app.com.error.log just has a bunch of these lines:

```
[Fri Apr 19 15:19:54 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Ubuntu-1204-precise-64-minimal' does NOT match server name!?
```

(BTW: The install default 'Ubuntu-1204-precise-64-minimal' was changed in my hostname and hosts files long ago so I have no idea why it pops up here...)

The ssl-access.log is empty.

My certs are in the correct folders and are readable (private key obv. only by root) and I have tried using the default snake oil certs as a test also. The result is the same. I am sure the site is enabled (it is the only one enabled), I am sure mod_ssl is enabled, and I am sure apache is listening on 443.

I've tried commenting out many of the directives one at a time and restarting but none make any difference. If I disable this site and re-enable default I get to the default index.html site no problem, but once SSL and HTTPS enter the picture I can't get what I want. I'm out of ideas!

Does anyone have any insight for me?

**Update**

Output of *sudo ufw status verbose*

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
115/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
25/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp                     LIMIT IN    Anywhere
80/tcp (Apache)            ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
115/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
25/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (Apache (v6))       ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: The certificate you use "/etc/ssl/private/my-app.com.key", was it signed with your server name "login.my-app.com"?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know, but is there some way I can double check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your ufw Apache app config file in /etc/ufw/applications.d/apache2.2-common
and make sure that you have the proper rule enabled.
It looks like you just have the [Apache] rule enabled which is default to allow port 80 only. You probably want the [Apache Full] rule enabled which will allow port 80 and port 443 traffic or [Apache Save] only allow port 443 only.

---

Original:

This might be a silly question, but did you check the configuration of your firewall as well. 
I'm assuming that you use the default UFA

Check the status with: **sudo ufw status verbose**

For further information see:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW

Comment: Output shown in update above

Comment: See edit above...

Comment: D'Oh! That was totally it; port 443 was blocked and the [Apache Full] rule opened it. When I looked at the apache2.2-common file the first time when I set the [Apache] rule I misunderstood it; I thought it was was somehow hierarchical... oops
Thanks!